# Arrange letters of a sentence in a minimum area?

Tags: algorithm

I'm going to write a program that rearranges letters of a sentence in a minimum area. The tool that I'm going to write this app is not important. The problem is that I nearly have no idea how I can do this.

I want something like this :

[image]

Is there any algorithm to sort some surfaces (let's suppose each letter a polygon surface) in a minimum area?

Comment: The problem of polygon packing is quite well known and by no means easy. Are arbitrary rotations possible, or just multiples of 180 degrees?

Comment: After narrating the story you need to say `So I think the question is`.  I'm speechless!

Comment: [Packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Packing_of_irregular_objects)

Comment: @JanDvorak http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JanDvorak ~> Yes . It's possible.

Comment: @Barmar "this question covers ... a software algorithm". Does it not?

Comment: @devnull~> :D That's because of my not so good English writing.

Comment: since arbitrary rotations are possible, any polygon packing algorithm will work here. The restriction to letter forms is unlikely to give significant bonus. I also assume the target shape is a rectangle?

Comment: @JanDvorak ~> Yes target is rectangle !

Comment: @devnull~> Updated :-|

Comment: This is a variation on the general [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem.  Even many simple scenarios of the problem (with nice rectangular shapes) have been shown to be [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), which is to say very slow/expensive computationally, though often there are "heuristics" that can usually achieve "pretty good" packing with much less computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this paper](http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf) you can find insights of Wordle, a tool to do beautiful tag clouds. It does a randomized greedy algorithm approximation of the bin packing problem.

Answer (score 5):

Its not easy at all...  it is related to the "Bin Packing Problem" which is proven NP-HARD.
Additionally, your problem involves non-rectangular objects so it's a bit harder but not by magnitude.

you should go for an Optimization algorithm approach like Genetic Algorithms or such...

Google for "Bin Packing 2D" will result in quite a few helpful links and articles.

Answer (score 2):

My approch for such an algorithm would be a genetic one.This would be a sample data structure sample in Java.

```
public class Individual{
 char letter;
 double x;
 double y;
 double rotation;
}

public class Population{
 private Individual[] individuals;

 public Population(String s) {
  individuals = new Individual[s.length()];  
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ {
   Individual individual = new Individual();
   individual.letter = s.charAt(i);
   // set random x, y, and rotation;
   individuals[i] = individual; 
  } 
 }
 // Calculate Fitness: (1/Totalspace needed ) - Overlapping Space
 // Envolve Population
}
```